# Responsive html css Curly Braces .brace.bottom:after not working

Tags: html, css

I have a some code for Responsive  **html css Curly Braces** i trying to place the bottom position but its not working correctly . position top is working perfect. anyone know how to change that position to bottom.
Thanks

**That's my code**

```css
.brace{
  border: 2px solid #CCC;
  height: 25px;
  position:relative;
  border-bottom: 0;
  border-radius: 25px 25px 0 0;
  margin-top: 25px;
}
.brace.top:after{
  content: '';
  position:absolute;
  left: 50%;
  width: 50px;
  height: 55px;
  margin-top: -27px;
  margin-left: -25px;
  background-color: #FFF;
  background:
    linear-gradient(135deg, transparent 10px, #CCC 0) top left,
    linear-gradient(225deg, transparent 10px, #CCC 0) top right,
    linear-gradient(315deg, transparent 10px, #CCC 0) bottom right,
    linear-gradient(45deg,  transparent 10px, #CCC 0) bottom left;
  background-size: 50% 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image:
    radial-gradient(circle at 0 0, transparent 25px, #CCC 26px, #FFF 28px ),
    radial-gradient(circle at 100% 0, transparent 25px, #CCC 26px, #FFF 28px),none,none;
}
.brace.bottom{
  border-top: 0;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #CCC;
  border-radius: 0 0 25px 25px;
  margin-top: 0;
}
.brace.bottom:after{
  content: '';
  position:absolute;
  left: 50%;
  width: 50px;
  height: 55px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-left: -25px;
  background-color: #FFF;
  background:
    linear-gradient(135deg, transparent 10px, #25aae1 0) top left,
    linear-gradient(225deg, transparent 10px, #25aae1 0) top right,
    linear-gradient(315deg, transparent 10px, #25aae1 0) bottom right,
    linear-gradient(45deg,  transparent 10px, #25aae1 0) bottom left;
  background-size: 50% 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image:
    radial-gradient(circle at 0 0, transparent 25px, #25aae1 26px, #25aae1 28px ),
    radial-gradient(circle at 100% 0, transparent 25px, #25aae1 26px, #25aae1 28px),none,none;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="content">
  <div class="brace top"></div>
  <br>

      <div class="brace bottom"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Do u want the ".brace.top:after" in bottom position?

Comment: `.brace.top:after` is what creates the actual “spike” on top. You have no counterpart for `brace.bottom` in your CSS yet – so what is your actual question …?

Comment: @04FS , i update my code, now you can see my issue, its not rotating

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plz follow these steps.. Depends on relative the bottom position will be aligned..

```css
.brace {
  position: static;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.brace.top::after {
  margin-top: 0;
  bottom: -28px;
}

.brace.bottom:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  width: 50px;
  height: 55px;
  margin-top: -4px;
  margin-left: -25px;
  background-color: #FFF;
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, transparent 10px, #CCC 0) top left, linear-gradient(225deg, transparent 10px, #CCC 0) top right, linear-gradient(315deg, transparent 10px, #CCC 0) bottom right, linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 10px, #CCC 0) bottom left;
  background-size: 50% 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle at 0 0, transparent 25px, #CCC 26px, #FFF 28px), radial-gradient(circle at 100% 0, transparent 25px, #CCC 26px, #FFF 28px), none, none;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="brace top"></div>
    <br>

    <div class="brace bottom"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks , i added your solution but middle one is not display and not changed

Comment: look my code,first one is ok i want to do like it for the  Curly Braces  bottom

Comment: can u plz share ur output screen ? Do u want top and bottom curve image?

Comment: I modified some changes plz check my below comments